# How to trigger an event when google map marker is dropped at a certain location on screen?

Tags: android, google-maps, events, drag-and-drop, marker

The google map marker can be dragged around the screen so I want to know if there's a way to trigger an event when the marker is dropped at a certain location on the screen, say, bottom left.

Comment: check https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After layout created and map initialized add the following code in onCreate();

```
    View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getView();
if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
           mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CENTER, 15));
            Point markerScreenPosition = map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
            int x = markerScreenPosition.getX();
            int y = markerScreenPosition.getY();
            if(x == yourValue && y == yourValue){
               //your trigger code goes here   
             }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No by location I meant the screen location (x,y) co ordinates as I've mentioned like bottom left of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think markers are not automatically dropped. they are handled by your code. for example you can add a marker on map click or on map long click. get that event and try fixing

Comment: It can be made draggable by setting `.draggable(true)` I want to know how to trigger a event based on where its dropped on the screen like bottom corner like I've asked

Comment: In that case you can [Try This](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener)